# Оформление таблиц matplotlib и seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, графика, matplotlib, seaborn

Помогите с помощью матплота или сеаборн вывести графики таблицей. например 4 графика по горизонтали и 3 по вертикали. и на каждом графике коореляция одной из переменных от "SalePrice"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот кусок кода, как только не пытался вывести эти графики чтоб аккуратно таблицей были уложенны и не надо было листать, помещались на экране))

```
sns.pairplot(train, y_vars = ["SalePrice"], x_vars = ('MasVnrArea', 'LotArea', 'BsmtFinSF1', 
'BsmtUnfSF', 'TotalBsmtSF', '1stFlrSF'))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
этот код выводит в ряд их только, создаю сабплот и выводит таблицы в столбец как на втором скрине
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4, len(qualitative)/4,figsize=(4*len(qualitative), 4))
sns.pairplot(trainInt, y_vars = ["SalePrice"], x_vars = ('MSSubClass', 'LotFrontage', 'LotArea', 
'OverallQual', 'OverallCond', 'YearBuilt'))
```

последним методом кое как вывел дисплоты в ряд, но все равно не смог адаптировать к графикам коореляции
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(round(len(qualitative)/5), 5, figsize=(40, 100))
for var, subplot in zip(qualitative, ax.flatten()):
    sns.set(font_scale = 1.5) 
    sns.regplot(x = var, y = 'SalePrice', data = trainAnaliticQ, ax = subplot);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]